# PHP exec in background using & is not working

Tags: php, linux, background, command

I am using this code on Ubuntu 13.04,

```
$cmd = "sleep 20 &> /dev/null &";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

Although it actually sits there for 20 seconds and waits :/ usually it works fine when using `&` to send a process to the background, but on this machine php just won't do it :/
What could be causing this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
<?PHP
$cmd = '/bin/sleep';
$args = array('20');

$pid=pcntl_fork();
if($pid==0)
{
  posix_setsid();
  pcntl_exec($cmd,$args,$_ENV);
  // child becomes the standalone detached process
}

echo "DONE\n";
```

I tested it for it works.
Here you first fork the php process and then exceute your task.

Or if the pcntl module is not availabil use:

```
<?PHP

$cmd = "sleep 20 &> /dev/null &";
exec('/bin/bash -c "' . addslashes($cmd) . '"');
```

Comment: always add a description of you answer.

Comment: `CMD=> nohup sleep 20 &> /dev/null &

This page was run in 20.082479000092 seconds

array(0) { }` didn't work :(

Comment: Changed my answer to a tested version.

Comment: the only problem is that it requires having a version of PHP compiled with pcntl enabled, which I don't :(

Comment: Changed my answer againe. Sorry but your solution is an bad idea because it is a realy huge securety lag.

Comment: Well it's slow, but not too much of a security issue since only localhost can login and the webserver user is custom and has very little access. But your solution worked great :D why does -c make it work?

Comment: Mats explained it well the "&> /dev/null &" is parsed by the shell. Why i have done "bash -c" is let the Born Againe Shell interprete it.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it wasn't being sent to bash :(

Comment: @GreenRover I wish I could upvote your answer more than once... Solution with `-c` & `addslashes` is ONLY thing that works now, it seems. No other answer which can be googled is working. Did not tried the `pcntl`, though.

Answer (score 1):

The REASON this doesn't work is that `exec()` executes the string you're passing into it. Since `&` is interpreted by the shell as "execute in the background", but you don't execute a shell in your `exec` call, the `&` is just passed along with `20` to the `/bin/sleep` executable - which probably just ignores that.

The same applies to the redirection of output, since that is also parsed by the shell, not in exec.

So, you either need to find a way to fork your process (as described above), or a way to run the subprocess as a shell.

Comment: This is not true. `exec()` does launch a shell. One way you can detect the presence of the shell is by executing a command that the shell will consider invalid. For example, `echo "<?php exec('NonExistentCommand'); ?>" | php` will print something like "sh: NonExistentCommand: command not found". The `sh:` portion is coming from `sh` (`/bin/sh`)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround to do this on ubuntu 13.04 with Apache2 and any version of PHP:
`libssh2-php`, I just used `nohup $cmd &` inside a local SSH session using PHP and it ran it just fine the background, of course this requires putting certain security protocols in place, such as enabling SSH access for the webserver user, so it would have exec-like permissions then only allowing localhost to login to the webserver ssh account.